# Division from Array after Implode - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

How come i still can no divide and if i do i get a 0.

```
  exec("snmpget -v 2c -c public $host $oid | cut -d':' -f4 | sed -e 's/^[ ]*//'", $state);

print_r($state);
$seconds=86400;
$current_state=implode($state);
print($current_state);
$div=($current_state/86400);
print($div);
```

Comment: What are you dividing? What is the content of `$current_state` after you `implode()` i?

Comment: and the value of `$current_state` is...? should we just guess? Ok.. I'll guess it's really "banana", and you're trying to do `banana / 86400`.

Comment: @MarcB that is equal to zero...

Comment: My output from the exec is 2569200 and i want to divide it by 86400. my  $current_state after implode i get the #

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: exactly.

Comment: @louis: you're imploding a string, which will cause $current_state to be NULL (and output as a blank in your print(). null / 86400 = 0.

Comment: does it work when you cast your string to a different data type ?

Comment: Can we see the output of the print_r($state). just a guess but could there be a space at the end of the $current_state value like "223232 " maybe trim it first.

Comment: WOW i did not notice there were comments. sorry!

Comment: 'Array
(
    [0] => "2495100"
)
"2495100"0  <--- that zero is after dividing. '

Comment: @dm03514 sorry but im a NewB, how would i do that. If you are talking about making the data type into a int i tried. $current_state=(int) etc

Comment: the "2495100" is from the print($current_state) and the Array one is from the $state before implode

Comment: could someone post a good example of division using an array?

Comment: the type was String, i converted it to int but still not luck. I keep getting 0

Answer (score 1):

[implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) can take two parameters.

> string implode ( string $glue , array $pieces )

Comment: no, it can work with just an array input.. that's why there's `implode($glue, $array)` and `implode($array)` in the very docs you linked to.

Comment: Which is why I say "can take two parameters."

Comment: no, you said "requires two parameters" until you ninja-edited.

Comment: -1 unfortunately saying implode can take 2 params is not addressing his problem

Comment: the implode is taking the actual # i want from the Array, BUT when i divide i get 0. even if i print current_state before i divide i get the # itself as well.

Comment: I gotta say, just like on Reddit i have always been a lurker,  this is my first time posting on Stackflow (will need more time on it :) ) and the resp time is amazing. thanks guys. hopefully ill sort this out